# How can I apply a function containing $(this) to range of selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little issue. I want to validate a form using a generic function for all the inputs on the form. The function handles the complexities of different types of inputs, etc.

The call to the function looks as follows:

`$(":input[type='text']").blur(function() {validateMe($(this).attr("id"), button_arr);});`

The issue here is that `$(this)` seems to apply only to the first element "blurred", so that any blur events occurring after the first one applies the first selector blurred, if that makes any sense?

The `button_arr` part is of no consequence.

Is there any way to apply the `$(this)` to every element in the collection specified by `$(":input[type='text']")`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question makes no sense and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wLKBS/

Comment: Most likely your `validateMe` function is written in such a way that it stores the first id and never lets it go.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you mean this:

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function () {
    $(this).blur(function () {
        validateMe(this.id, button_arr);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you need to pass the `id`, please don't use jQuery to retrieve it, just use `this.id` (it's faster, cheaper and cross-browser compatible). Also, using the `:input` selector with `type=[text]`? That's comparable to, but slower than, `input[type="text"]`.

Comment: @DavidThomas You are right, I was just building on what TS had posted. Edited. :)

Comment: I don't see how this fixes anything. It's no different from the OP's original code, except it explicitly loops, instead of allowing `blur()` to do so internally

Comment: Nor me! it's the exact same behaviour as OP's code with an useless each loop

Comment: @Ian Now that you mention it, I didn't really think it through I guess. But the problem that is described does look like something goes wrong in the loop though. Only the first value is used. And because he mentions that multiple blur events occur, that might occur dynamically.

Comment: @BramVanroy But with the example, the looping is no different - like I said, it's a matter of explicit vs. implicit. jQuery set it up so that you **don't** have to explicitly loop like you have. I understand what the OP **meant**, but I doubt it has to do with the looping. KevinB just commented on the OP, and that makes most sense to me - something with `validateMe` is keeping the first call's parameter

Answer (score -1):

I guess

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function() {
    validateMe(this.id, button_arr);
});
```

should do it too? Why are you using the colon in the selector? I think it returns a set. So you could get rid of the unnecessary each-loop

EDIT:

I guess you mean the selector ":input", not ":input[type='text']"? Because your selector is only selecting the input-fields with the attribute "type" set to "text". Maybe you just got one of these? "textarea", "button" and "select" doesn't have an attribute "type" with value "text"

Comment: what is different from OP's code? (except this.id)

Comment: the colon in the selector. because the colon is returning the set of DOM-elements, while my selector without the colon doesn't. It's adding the blur event to every input[type='text'] element

Comment: `:input` is a shortcut for `input,select,textarea,button`, while `input` returns only elements of type input. They are not same selector

Comment: yes but why would i select the elements "select", "textarea" and "button" with "type='text'"? maybe thats the problem?

Comment: That's a good point! But will not cause any issues. In fact OP's code using :input was useless and your selector in this case is for sure better

Comment: The question is, does he want to select all elements in the form (buttons, textareas and select too) or only the input-fields with type='text'? I edited my post, think this could be a problem

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, the only type of input that can have `type=text` is an `<input>` element, so `:input` vs `input` is not important unless you're using an older browser.

Comment: @KevinB Well, `:input` is a jQuery selector, so it doesn't matter what browser it's in. But it definitely makes sense to use `input` because `:input` does more work (since it's custom) and looks for too many **unrelated** elements. Still, that should be communicated to the OP through comments, not an answer

Comment: The performance difference is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @KevinB Then what was your point about "unless you're using an older browser"?